# How to find the nth prime in C

Tags: c

This application will receive a number `n`. After receiving this number, the program has to show the `n`-th prime in the list of primes. For example, if the user enters `3`, the program is supposed to display `5`, because `5` is the third prime starting at `2`. I know that something is wrong with my code but I don't know where the problem is and how I can fix it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, flag, prime;
    int counter = 1;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n == 1) prime = 2;
    else
        do{
            prime = 3;
            for (i = 2; i < prime; i++) {
                flag = 1;
                if (prime % i == 0) {
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }
            if (flag == 1)
                counter++;
            prime++;
        } while (counter != n);
    if (counter == n)
    printf("%d\n", prime);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will have to describe why do you think that this code is wrong. And be specific, explain what output it prints, what do you expect and why do you think this happens. Just doing an exercise like that will most likely give you an answer.

Comment: Don't know if you care but using a sieve algorithm (eratosthenes or atkins) will speed up your function dramatically for larger numbers.

Comment: This code is short and fairly simple, and the n=3 case doesn't run long; you should be able to step through it, either on paper or with the help of `printf` statements, and see exactly how it goes wrong.

Comment: e.g Standard Input:3
    Standard Ouput:5
    My Input:3
    My out put:4
Whaterer I input except 1,it prints 4...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix sample of remains of your policy like this :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int n, i, flag, prime;
    int counter = 1;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n == 1)
        prime = 2;
    else {
        prime = 1;
        do{
            prime += 2;
            flag = 1;
            for (i = 3; i < prime; i+=2){
                if (prime % i == 0) {
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag == 1)
                counter++;
        } while (counter != n);
    }
    printf("%d\n", prime);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And the algorithm you share is much better!

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting flag to 1 every time through the loop, so 'flag' will only tell you if prime is divisible by "prime-1", which of course it never is.